# How to use artoolkitx_genMarkerSet in artoolkitx?

Tags: windows-10, artoolkit

I'm now developing an web ar project, using ar.js ,and I need to create .patt file.
And then I downloaded the newest version of artoolkitx: 1.1.3 on my Windows 10 PC.

The artoolkitx_genTexData.exe can generate the iset file perfectly,
But artoolkitx_genMarkerSet.exe cann't generate the patt file...
All I got is the following picture.

[image: Snapshot]
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

genMarkerSet looks for square areas with a border (usually a black border on a white background, but it is possible to run the software so it will look for a white border on a black background).

Try making sure your picture you wish to track is inside a square border.